# What is the proper way to implement authentication in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

ok so I've built a few apps in Firebase and really enjoy using the simple API but always struggle with auth. see this code

I have a simple email and password "form" (not a form element, just two inputs)
and then a button (div) I click to call this function below

```
const logUserIn = () => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('here') // this WORKS but the history redirect below does not work :/
            localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(res))
            history.push('/account')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error)
        })
}
```

however when I put the lines below

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            console.log('user logged in')
        } else {
            console.log('user not logged in')
        }
    })
```

it seemed to pick it up correctly

but my question is, what is the point of `signInWithEmailAndPassword`? and also, how do I use both functions together? do I need to call `onAuthStateChanged` in the `.then` part of my `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function?

it's really confusing how to have a consistent state. my app seems to work after I refresh the page but I want it to work without refreshes (obviously)

any ideas on the best approach?

EDIT

also when I click sign out

```
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        history.push('/account')
    } else {
        console.log('NO USER')
    }
})
```

`NO USER` logs but then I click on an authenticated route it takes me there until I refresh

Answer (score 0):

The point of `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is to allow the implementation of classic username/password authentication for people who don't have a Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc. account. If you decide to add it, Google will handle the user accounts and everything, but you'll have to build the login form, complete with the *I forgot my password* and *Register as new user* links. Other than that it's simply another provider.

I have a very simple little project on my Github repo which implements user/password authentication along with several others, I suggest you to look into it. I made it as a test assignment for a job interview. It's Angular.
https://github.com/tomcatmwi/morbidomega

Comment: ok sure but can you point me to relevant auth parts.  I normally use react so im use to that setup

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? How to use email auth?

Comment: just a simple way to log users in and out

Comment: It doesn't get any simpler than this.